# Is there a tool which visualizes VBA code via e.g. a flow chart?

Tags: vba, excel, visualization, flowchart

If possible, also run through all modules in an excel application.

Answer (score 3):

Flowchart would be something useful. I have never seen something similar for code, but there are a few VBA tools, that you may find interesting. These are the ones that I know: http://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-professional-tools-for-vba

In general, concerning code, [MZ-Tools](https://www.mztools.com) has a good option to show the statistics of the used code. This is how it looks like:

[image]

Then you can save it as a `*.txt` file, edit it a bit and load it into Excel. From there you can make your own charts easily, if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub copyobject()
        Dim drawing As AcadEntity
        Dim copyobject As Object
        Dim pickpoint As Variant
        Dim pastpoint As Variant
        On Error Resume Next
        ThisDrawing.Utility.GetEntity drawing, pickpoint,  “ Pick entity to copy”
         If drawing Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "You did not pick an object"
            Exit Sub
        End If
Set copyobject = drawing.Copy()
        pastpoint = ThisDrawing.Utility.GetPoint(, "Pick point to copy to: ")
        
        'put the object in its new position
        copyobject.Move pickpoint, pastpoint
        
        copyobject.Update
        ZoomExtents
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).